# Excel - Fill Table Range from another Table Range meeting specific criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, named-ranges

I have 2 tables on seperate worksheets, basically a WBS sheet and another Gant chart sheet.
I am trying to populate the Gant Chart sheet with WBS data for Level 1 and 2 tasks only.

**WBS**

```
|Level| WBS |Description|
| 1   |1    | Task 1    |
| 2   |1.1  | Task 1.1  |
| 3   |1.1.1| Task 1.1.1|
| 1   |2    | Task 2    |
```

**GANT**

```
| WBS |Description|
|1    | Task 1    |
|1.1  | Task 1.1  |
|2    | Task 2    |
```

I have tried If's, lookups, index, match, etc. but nothing has worked for me so far.
To make it slightly harder the ranges have different origin points WBS - A1 and Gant - A8

I can populate the list by using the array command {=WBS} but that copies everything.

Comment: This gets me half way there, it puts a bunch of blank cells in though because of the if not
=IF(OFFSET(WBS[@Level],-6,0)<3,OFFSET(WBS[@Level],-6,1),"")

Comment: you may try : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z-h2UER3b_0&t=103s ( I find the filter function part solves the 'blank cells' you mentioned.. )

Answer (score 0):

Here's my favorite 'manual' solution

Assuming 'level' is cell A1 in WBS sheet, add another column in WBS table that do : `=IF(OR(A2=1,A2=2),D1+1,D1)`

& drag donwards.

In the 'GANT' sheet add another list of 1,2,3.. then used index/match on WBS sheet to 'load' the other row values. ref : https://exceljet.net/index-and-match